# Another Failure to install pyjags

Tags: python, windows, pip

Please help me to install pyjags on Anaconda windows environment. Both pip and easy_install give error messages as follows:

```
>pip install pyjags
Collecting pyjags
  Using cached pyjags-1.2.2.tar.gz (79 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aliyu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-odiec3d9\\pyjags\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aliyu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-odiec3d9\\pyjags\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\aliyu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-odiec3d9\pyjags\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\aliyu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-odiec3d9\pyjags\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Package jags was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `jags.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'jags' found
    Error while executing pkg-config: Command '['pkg-config', '--libs', '--cflags', 'jags']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command error out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

```
>easy_install pyjags
WARNING: The easy_install command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Searching for pyjags
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/pyjags/
Downloading [files.pythonhosted][1]
Best match: pyjags 1.2.2
Processing pyjags-1.2.2.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\aliyu\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-b_pvpypz\pyjags-1.2.2\setup.cfg
Running pyjags-1.2.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\aliyu\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-b_pvpypz\pyjags-1.2.2\egg-dist-tmp-3sqcbrtt
Package jags was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `jags.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'jags' found
Error while executing pkg-config: Command '['pkg-config', '--libs', '--cflags', 'jags']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
error: Setup script exited with 1
```

I look forward to your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear:

> `Package jags was not found`

And a quick look at the [pypi project page](https://pypi.org/project/pyjags/#description) reveals the same:

> PyJAGS provides a Python interface to JAGS

So `pyjags` is only an interface to `jags`. In order to use this interface (and first to install it) you will need to have `jags`. Officially, there are windows files available [from here](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/), but `pyjags` officially only supports POSIX operating systems (also see the [pypi project page](https://pypi.org/project/pyjags/#description)), so it is not guaranteed to be installable even if you manage to get JAGS working on you operating system

Comment: Teller, Many thanks for your insights. I have already installed jags and rjags. I am already using it in R and thought that it will be a breeze to install in Python!

Answer (score 0):

Really late, but as the question deserves an answer, from [pyjags page](https://github.com/michaelnowotny/pyjags):

> PyJAGS works on MacOS and Linux. Windows is not currently supported.